# Cannot Upgrade Xcode App Crashes After IOS 7.0.3 Upgrade

Tags: xcode, crash, ios7, updates

I am in a world of pain so confused.

I have updated my ipad and iphone to ios7.

I have been developing with titanium mobile and when i open my project in xcode and trying to run on the device i now get this error.

> No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS
>   version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to
>   run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

So after googling around i notice i am running xcode Version 4.6.3 (4H1503). So i thought i might need to be update.

So i went to the mac store found xcode and then clicked update, and i know get this error.

```
Xcode can’t be installed on “Macintosh HD” because Mac OS X version 10.8.4 or later is required.
```

So i done some more googling and now i am here all the links i find take me back to the app store where i get the above error.

Can someone please help, after updating to io7 version 7.0.3. My app now crashes so i need to debug on the device to find out why this is happen

Help

UPDATE
my mac is running Software  Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 (11G63) and when i click check for updates i get this alert.

```
Software Update doesn’t have any new software for your computer at this time.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your mac to the OS X Mavericks. Click the Apple icon on the top left and select "App Store...". Search for "Mavericks". Click "Free upgrade" (yes it is free :-). After that you will be able to upgrade Xcode to 5.x release.